# Зависает форма c# при чтении com порта

Tags: c#, com-порт

Здравствуйте. Я здесь новенький, поэтому сразу простите, если что-то оформлю не так. Проблема следующая:
Устройство пишет множество строк (по объёму около 600мб)  в порт. Скорость 1000000. Программа должна писать все строки в файл txt. Проблема в том, что через 10-15 секунд работы программа начинает зависать. Если я даю команду на закрытие порта, то но этой команде всё и зависает окончательно. В отладчике видно, что myport.Close() так и не выполняется до конца (ждал несколько минут).

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 1000000;
        myport.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_DataReceived;
        try
        {
            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {
                myport.Close();
                myport.Open();

            }
            else
            {
                myport.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        if (myport.IsOpen)
        {
       }
    }


public async void myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        in_data = myport.ReadLine();

        if (in_data != null)
        {
           byte[] b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(in_data);
           string myFilePath = @"C:\Users\Sergej\OneDrive\testc#\test.txt";
           File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, (b[0] - 14).ToString() + (b[1] - 14).ToString() + (b[2] - 14).ToString() + (b[3] - 14).ToString() + (b[4] - 14).ToString() + (b[5] - 14).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);}}
```

Comment: `File.AppendAllText()` не подходит для вашей задачи. Нужно писать в файл с помощью потока, используйте `StreamWriter`.